# Flutter Firebase Stream<QuerySnapshot?> Pagination

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I'm creating a chat functionality in a flutter app using Firebase, everything is working fine except every time I open the chat I'll get the whole conversation. so I want to implement Pagination to get 20 messages at a time. I tried multiple solution but nothing work.

HERES HOW I GET THE MESSAGES

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot?> getMessages(
      {required String reciverId,
      required String senderId,
      required String productId}) {
    //
    // GET CHAT ID
    String chatRoomId = genrateChatId(
      sender: senderId,
      reciverId: reciverId,
      productId: productId,
    );

    return _firestore
        .collection(chatCollectionName)
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

AND HERES HOW I DISPLAY THEM

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: chatCubit.getMessages(
                senderId: chatParties.senderId,
                reciverId: chatParties.reciverId,
                productId: chatParties.productId,
              ),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                          bottom: 100.0, start: 30, end: 30),
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context)!.somethingwrongtryagain,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        maxLines: 4,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                final documents = snapshot.data!.docs;

                if (documents.isEmpty) {
                  isFirstTime = true;
                  return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                          bottom: 100.0, start: 30, end: 30),
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                            .sendmessagestostartconversation,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        maxLines: 4,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                List<Message> messages = [];
                int? currentUserId = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'id');

                for (var document in documents) {
                  Message message = Message(
                    id: document["id"],
                    text: document["text"],
                    senderId: document["senderId"],
                    timestamp: document["timestamp"],
                    isSeen: document["isSeen"],
                    isSent: document["isSent"],
                    productId: document["productId"],
                    replies: [],
                  );

                  messages.add(message);
                }

                isFirstTime = false;

                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                        },
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: messages.length,
                          reverse: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final Message message = messages[index];
                            return MessageWidget(
                              message: message.text,
                              sender:
                                  message.senderId == currentUserId.toString(),
                              timestamp: message.timestamp,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 70),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
```

HERES HOW I TRY TO GET THE OLDER MESSAGES

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chatParties = getChatPartiesInfo(conversation: widget.conversation);
    scrollController.addListener(getMoreData);
  }

  getMoreData() {
    if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent ==
        scrollController.position.pixels) {
      ChatCubit.get(context).getMessages(
        senderId: chatParties.senderId,
        reciverId: chatParties.reciverId,
        productId: chatParties.productId,
        lastDocument: messagesDocuments.last,
      );
    }
  }
```

So I tried 2 ways to make the pagination first is when the user scroll up I will call getMessages function and send the last document.

would be like

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getMessages({
    required String reciverId,
    required String senderId,
    required String productId,
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? lastDocument,
  }) {
    String chatRoomId = genrateChatId(
      sender: senderId,
      reciverId: reciverId,
      productId: productId,
    );

    Query<Map<String, dynamic>> baseQuery = _firestore
        .collection(chatCollectionName)
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
        .limit(20);

    if (lastDocument != null) {
      baseQuery = baseQuery.startAfterDocument(lastDocument);
    }

    return baseQuery.snapshots();
  }
```

So the function enter the condition but I don't receive any old messages.

I tried the same thing with timestamp but still I don't get the old messages.

```
where('timestamp', isLessThan: lastMessageTimeStamp);
```

I'm expecting to get the old chat when the user scroll to the top.